# How to install Necta WiFi mouse

Tags: wireless, software-installation, mouse

I want to use my tablet as WiFi mouse, so I have seen an Youtube video in which user provided [WiFi Mouse](http://wifimouse.necta.us/) link for downloading. I have installed it but I am not able to launch it.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought you may not be able to use that on Linux (Ubuntu). Read their [page](http://wifimouse.necta.us/):

> Compatible with XP/Windows Vista/ Windows 7 / Mac OSX

By looking further on that site I can see that they have developed a Linux app.

These kind of software solutions are made up of an Android app that installs on your phone/tablet and another app that should be installed on the computer you want to control.

And apparently there is such an application available - [x86](http://wifimouse.necta.us/MouseServerLinux32.zip); [x64](http://wifimouse.necta.us/MouseServerLinux64.zip).

If you already installed the `deb` package with `sudo dpkg -i mouseserver*.deb` and you are unable to start it, in a Terminal run

```
/usr/sbin/mouseserver
```

The Linux app has no interface except a status icon that is invisible and if you manage to right click on it you can see your IP address, some info about the app and you can quit (close it).

Here is how it looks when started:

[image]

In your Dash it's the first app, the one without icon. Click on it to start it.

Then use your Android device. Launch **WiFi Mouse** and select your PC or enter its IP manually and tap the Link icon.

[image]

Comment: Any other software suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to check in and confirm that this is still works on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Steps to get running:

1. Visit http://wifimouse.necta.us/#setup to download the app and server
2. On Ubuntu, run `sudo dpkg -i mouseserver*.deb` to install the deb
3. Run `/usr/sbin/mouseserver` to launch the server. 
   If the server is running, your terminal should print a message like `mouse server[10656]: started on port 1978`
4. Use `ipconfig` command to get your IP.
5. Launch the phone app and enter your IP. The app should show a mousepad and the terminal will print inputs once you have successfully connected.